# The google cloud alarms, activate them only in a range of hours per day?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I'm trying to program alarms in real time in google cloud with queries in the log, I need an alarm that only activates depending on the time of day, for example:

From 9:00 a.m. to 4:00 p.m., if the alarm occurs, send an email
From 4:00 p.m. to 9:00 a.m., if the alarm occurs, we ignore it and do not send the alert to the email.

Also on Tuesday I wanted to know if there is any way to configure the day of the week, that is, for Monday, Wednesday and we activate the alarm notification, for the rest of the days we do not.

I am trying to see if it can be done in the google log query but it seems very complex.